# How to escape special characters in taglib files in JSF?

Tags: xml, jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2

I have created a custom tag in JSF as follows as defined in `my.taglib.xml` file.

```
<namespace>http://example.com/ui</namespace>

<tag>
    <tag-name>viewParamValidationFailed</tag-name>
    <attribute>
        <name>redirect</name>
        <required>true</required>            
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
        <description>Location to redirect, in case validation/s or conversion/s of view parameters as specified by the <![CDATA[<o:viewParam>]]> tag fails.</description>
    </attribute>

    <handler-class>tags.ViewParamValidationFailed</handler-class>
</tag>
```

This tag can be used on XHTML pages as follows.

```xml
xmlns:my="http://example.com/ui"

<my:viewParamValidationFailed redirect="Location.jsf"/>
```

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0. When <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is pressed to show the description of the `redirect` attribute, the IDE shows the following text.

> Location to redirect, in case validation/s or conversion/s of view
>   parameters as specified by the   tag fails.

Please notice that `<o:viewParam>` enclosed within `CDATA` in the tag description is missing in this text- `as specified by the___tag fails.`

How to escape such special characters in such taglib files so that the description is shown correctly?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of CDATA?

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` make no difference - yield the same problem. Already tried prior to this post.

Comment: I've had to double the escapes once while using doclets. I believe the description might be similar. I posted an answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the contents of the description box are similar to the *escaped HTML* that you can include in *doclets* (used in Javadocs). So, if you want to make part of your description **bold**, you can't enclose the text in a `<strong>` element, but you must enclose it in an escaped version of it: `&lt;strong&gt;`. For example, if you use:

```
<description>Location to &lt;strong&gt;redirect&lt;/strong&gt;, in ...</description>
```

The text will appear in the description box as

> Location to **redirect**, in ...

but if you use regular tags they will simply disappear.

That means that if you actually want to *display* the tag, you will need to *double* the escapes. Either use `&amp;&lt;` and `&amp;gt;` for the angle brackets, or use escaped angle brackets inside the `CDATA`. I didn't test it but I am quite certain that this should work:

```
<![CDATA[&lt;o:viewParam&gt;]]>
```